# Select HTML usando dados do banco ficam em branco

Tags: php, html, mysql

Fiz o select e no banco de dados quando cadastro o valor do select salva normalmente, porém no momento da seleção não é exibido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CÓDIGO

```
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Fornecedor</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="fornecedor">
           <option>Selecione o Fornecedor</option>
           <?php
            $result = "select nm_forn from tb_fornecedor";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($connection, $result);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
              echo '<option value="'.$row['nm_forn'].'"></option>';
            }
           ?>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você faz a busca no banco você define o valor da opção do select, mas não colocou o que vai ser exibido. Seu código deveria ser algo como:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['nm_forn'].'">'.$row['nm_forn'].'</option>';
```

Onde coloquei o `$row['nm_forn']` que não está no seu código deve ir o texto da option, pode ser qualquer coisa, coloquei o que daria para inferir com base no seu código.

Answer (score -2):

777- O teu echo está simplesmente no value, deves dar um echo também no Option

```
<option value=<?=Seu Resultado?>> <?=Seu Resultado?> </option>
```